# la notion de/du temps

Tags: grammaire, articles

Quelle est la différence entre ces deux expressions ?

> - La notion de temps
> - La notion du temps

Answer (score 6):

D'un point de vue du sens :

La *notion de temps* renvoie plutôt à une manière de concevoir le temps, elle met l'emphase sur le mot *temps*.

> - La notion de temps chez Platon.
> - Une réflexion sur la notion de temps.

La notion du temps renvoie plutôt à une expression qui souligne notre rapport à la temporalité.

> - Cela fait une semaine que je n'ai pas regardé ma montre, je n'ai plus la notion du temps.
> - J'ai perdu la notion du temps depuis que je travaille sur ce projet.